# Removing code for mobile screen menu

Tags: html, css

I have the following code which adds/removes a .show-nav and .hide-nav class to my navigation. This is applied to the  .mobile-nav div with the .toggle-nav button.

functions.php

```
$(function() {

// Bind a click event to anything with the class "toggle-nav"
$('.toggle-nav').click(function() {
    if ($('.mobile-nav').hasClass('show-nav')) {
        $('.mobile-nav').removeClass('show-nav').addClass('hide-nav');

        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.mobile-nav').removeClass('hide-nav');
        }, 500);

    } else {
        $('.mobile-nav').removeClass('hide-nav').addClass('show-nav');
    }

    return false;
});

});
```

.mobile-nav is a full screen overlay menu which I only want to use on mobile devices so I remove the .toggle-nav button on screen size ( >768px). .mobile-nav remains invisible until .toggle-nav is clicked.

css

```
.toggle-nav { display: none; }

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

.toggle-nav { display: inline-block; }
}
```

Problem is if the mobile-nav is 'opened' and the user makes the screen large, the toggle-nav button is hidden but the menu remains open.

Basically, I want the class .hide-nav applied (or .show-nav is removed) if the screen goes larger than 768px.

Comment: just add class on window resize ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a short example of  things need to be done. Added some jquery codes to make it work the way you want .

> **Step 1** - Add class `hide-nav` on **window width**

```
 /* logic For window width */
  if ($(window).width() > 768) {
    $('.mobile-nav').addClass('hide-nav');
  } else {
    $('.mobile-nav').removeClass('hide-nav');
  }
```

> **Step 2 -** Add class `hide-nav` on **window resize**

```
  /* logic For Window Resize */
  function resize() {
    if ($(window).width() > 768) {
      $('.mobile-nav').addClass('hide-nav');
    }

    $('.mobile-nav').addClass('hide-nav');
  }

  $(window).resize(resize)
    .trigger('resize');
```

```js
$(function() {

  // Bind a click event to anything with the class "toggle-nav"
  $('.toggle-nav').click(function() {
    if ($('.mobile-nav').hasClass('show-nav')) {
      $('.mobile-nav').removeClass('show-nav').addClass('hide-nav');

      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.mobile-nav').removeClass('hide-nav');
      }, 500);

    } else {
      $('.mobile-nav').removeClass('hide-nav').addClass('show-nav');
    }

    return false;
  });


  /* logic For window width */
  if ($(window).width() > 768) {
    $('.mobile-nav').addClass('hide-nav');
    $('.mobile-nav').removeClass('show-nav');
  } else {
    $('.mobile-nav').removeClass('hide-nav');
  }

  /* logic For Window Resize */
  function resize() {
    if ($(window).width() > 768) {
      $('.mobile-nav').addClass('hide-nav');
      $('.mobile-nav').removeClass('show-nav');
    }

    $('.mobile-nav').addClass('hide-nav');
  }

  $(window).resize(resize)
    .trigger('resize');

});
```

```css
.mobile-nav {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.show-nav {
  display: block;
}

.hide-nav {
  display: none
}

.toggle-nav {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .toggle-nav {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle-nav">Toggle Nav</div>

<div class="mobile-nav"></div>
```

Comment: That it does! however one request, I have the action have a remove-class action when it close (and an action when it opens)  Is it possible to have it 'act' like it was closed when the window gets resized to a larger screen? right now the menu just disappears

Comment: So when the browser is resized in case of above 768px the menu should appear what ever the case may be?